# How to integrate Paytm for accept payment in php

Tags: php, paytm

I want to integrate Paytm in php,I want to accept payments via paytm,
I tried with "Paytm_App_Checksum_Kit_PHP" in php

So whenever i open "generateChecksum.php" i am getting following results

```
{"CHECKSUMHASH":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=","ORDER_ID":null,"payt_STATUS":"1"}
```

And whenever i open "verifyChecksum.php",Then i am getting following results

```
Redirect back to the app
```

What is the next step ? or Where i am wrong ?

Comment: _“What is the next step ?”_ - probably to redirect back to your app, I guess …? You seem to be talking about a library here that has the sole purpose of generating and verifying a checksum … a hole payment flow probably involves a bit more than that. You should really start with the API documentation of the payment provider, and go read up on what steps need to be performed in what order.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the value for PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY in /lib/config_paytm.php file. (The value for MERCHANT_KEY will be provided after the onboarding process is completed). which will be present in your Paytm Dashboard.

```
<?php
//Change the value of PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY constant with details received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); 
?>
```

after that try to generate the checksum.